# How to get list of all Session Variables created in a Solution / Project

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on an existing ASP.NET / C# project. How can I find all session variables created in the project in different code behind / in line code / class file, without running the project in debug mode. I am using vs 2008.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do a global search in the solution for `Session.Add` and `Session["`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a global search using regular expression

Something like this may do the trick

```
(?:Session\[.+\]\s*=|Session.Add)
```

First part cover session variables created by assigment: `Session["MyVarName"] = myValue`

Second part cover session variables created using `Add` method: `Session.Add("MyVarName", myValue)`

Answer (score 0):

Do a search in your solution using the regular expression: `Session\[.*=` which would find cases where you might be setting a session variable like so:  `Session['foo'] = "bar"`.  Visual Studio allows you to do this using its search window: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd>  (to find all occurrences in the project)

Also, you could check for `Session.Add`.

Answer (score 0):

press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> and type:

> session[

and from drop down select search in project